# First value of for loop is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a JavaScript table from scratch. I'm trying to print out a series of values from an array - these would be the table heads, but for this question I have them as paragraphs.

There should be four values, but five values end up being printed. The first value comes out "undefined," but the other four values print out as intended. Here is the code:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script>

var headArray = ["Artist", "Album", "Year", "Genre"];

var tableHead = function() {
    var str;
    for (var i = 0; i < headArray.length; i++) {
        str == "";
        str += '<p>';
        str += headArray[i];
        str += '</p>';
        console.log(str);
    }
    return str;
}

var x = document.getElementById('test');
x.innerHTML = tableHead();

    </script>
```

When the HTML is run the document shows: undefined Artist Album Year Genre.

The console.log shows:

```
"undefined<p>Artist</p>" 
"undefined<p>Artist</p><p>Album</p>" 
"undefined<p>Artist</p><p>Album</p><p>Year</p>" 
"undefined<p>Artist</p><p>Album</p><p>Year</p><p>Genre</p>"
```

How can I prevent and/or remove undefined values from printing in the DOM? Keep in mind this is just the first part of a larger project (I am building a table after all).

Comment: str == ""; instead of str = "";

Comment: Initialize str outside loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for "undefined" in your console.log() is that you never initialized `str`. In the first line of your `for` loop, you have `str == ""`. This is a comparison of the value of `str` to an empty string. Because `str` was not initialized, the return of that is `undefined`.

It would appear that you're trying to initialize your variable, but that should be done outside of your for loop. If you change from `str == ""` to `str = ""` and look at your `<div id="test"></div>` after this code runs, you'll only see the result of the last iteration. This is because you are setting `str` to a new string every pass.

This is what you'll need to do. With this code, your console.log will always return the previous iterations as well. Otherwise your end-result table will only have the last header cell:

```
var headArray = ["Artist", "Album", "Year", "Genre"];

var tableHead = function() {
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < headArray.length; i++) {
        str += '<p>';
        str += headArray[i];
        str += '</p>';
        console.log(str);
    }
    return str;
}

var x = document.getElementById('test');
x.innerHTML = tableHead();
```

Comment: I literally figured this out 10 minutes ago, but I didn't delete the question because I'm sure someone else will have this problem. Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: You're welcome. Kudos to you for thinking about everyone else!

Answer (score 3):

You need to have `str` declared outside the loop or it will keep getting rewritten (as well as changing that `==` to a `=`:

```
var tableHead = function() {
  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < headArray.length; i++) {
    str += '<p>';
    str += headArray[i];
    str += '</p>';
  }
  return str;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xCZ33/4/)

Comment: I literally figured this out 10 minutes ago, but I didn't delete the question because I'm sure someone else will have this problem. Thank you for the great answer!

Answer (score 1):

javascript required some value, even if empty

```
 var str="";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
str == "";
```

to

```
str = "";
```

And initialize the variable str outside the loop

```
var str="";
```

Comment: And put it before the `for` loop.

Comment: It's undefined because of `var str;`, not because of a line of code that returns `false` and makes no change to the variable in question.